# Did Maimonides covertly condemn circumcision?

Tags: rambam, brit-milah

[Leo Strauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Strauss) argued that sophisticated writers communicate ideas through many layers of meaning and abstraction using rhetorical stratagems including self-contradiction and hyperbole to convey their proper meaning:

> Strauss indicates that medieval political philosophers, no less than their ancient counterparts, carefully adapted their wording to the dominant moral views of their time, lest their writings be condemned as heretical ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Strauss))

And of special interest to Strauss was Maimonides:

> Maimonides is the only author on whom Strauss wrote in each decade of his life. ... It was in and through his study of (and writing on) the [*Guide to the Perplexed*](https://sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp185.htm), that Strauss made his great rediscovery of the art of esoteric writing, by which philosophers communicate their serious thoughts only to the most intelligent and careful readers. ([Steven Lenzner](https://mosaicmagazine.com/picks/history-ideas/2016/10/what-leo-strauss-learned-from-moses-maimonides/), reviewing my Kenneth Hart Green's edition of *Leo Strauss on Maimonides: The Complete Writings*)

This is all to say that a serious contemporary philosopher believed mediaeval thinkers would often hide their meaning in between their lines to evade scrutiny from the authorities of the time. Above all, Maimonides! And indeed the Rambam himself explicitly warns the reader in his *Introduction* that:

> Any inconsistency discovered in the present work will be found to arise in consequence of the fifth cause or the seventh.

The fifth cause being *the use of a certain method adopted in teaching and expounding profound problems*, and the seventh *concealing the fact as much as possible, to prevent the uneducated reader from perceiving the contradiction.*

With that in mind, let us turn our attention to what Maimonides writes in [*Guide to the Perplexed*](https://sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp185.htm) about circumcision:

> 1. Circumcision is not like an incision on the leg, or a burning in the arm, but a very difficult operation;
> 2. Circumcision is [to be] performed when the child is very young [for] when a child is very young, the parents do not think much of him; because the image of the child, that leads the parents to love him, has not yet taken a firm root in their minds;
> 3. [Circumcision] gives to all members of the same faith, i.e., to all believers in the Unity of God, a common bodily sign, so that it is impossible for any one that is a stranger, to say that he belongs to them;
> 4. It is hard for a woman with whom an uncircumcised man has had sexual intercourse to separate from him, [and] in [his] opinion this is the strongest of the reasons for circumcision.

Could it be that he is covertly condemning it in between the lines? Firstly, he is saying that circumcision is a "very difficult", i.e. risky, operation (and here one must not forget that Maimonides *was* a physician!).

Secondly, his explanation for *brit milah* being performed on the 8th day of life has no relationship at all to scripture, but simply an opportunistic exploitation of the child's parents lack of compassion for him (especially the father's, as he points out).

Thirdly, the defense of circumcision as a mark of religious identity makes little sense for someone who lived his entire life amongst Muslims, who were also circumcised.

Lastly, and most critically, how is it that uncircumcised men being irresistible to women is a defense of circumcision? At all?? Did he not want Jewish men and women to marry? Did he not want them to stay married? Of course he did.

So what gives? It sounds like to me he is *explaining* circumcision, he is giving *reasons* for it, but not actually justifying it. In fact, much to the contrary! He is covertly condemning it by giving reasons that are in stark contradiction to the ethics he so eloquently advocates in *Pirkei Avot*.

As a final note, some may notice I did not include above Maimonides' statements that circumcision:

1. *is* painful, and
2. dulls sexual pleasure.

While these aspects may be in contradiction with modern Western ethic, they not necessarily are with the ethic Maimonides articulated and advocated.

Comment: No of course not, chas veshalom

Comment: So much leading here and stock full of logical holes, but a clear view of his opinion on circumcision is apparent from the end of his exposition on the laws of circumcision (see halachos 8-9) https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/932330/jewish/Milah-Chapter-Three.htm#v8

Comment: Well, ok, so how are we to make sense of those 4 apparent, or real, contradictions?

Comment: This is not the first time I've heard of scholars who base Rambam's theology solely on Guide to the Perplexed. The problem is that they decisively ignore Mishneh Torah and his other works. In the end, when challenged, they are forced to admit that Rambam was very much a traditional, believing Jew who kept the Torah and adhered to halacha, and halacha was very much important to him.

Comment: I'm neither a "scholar," nor am I attempting to sum up the Rambam's entire worldview, @Harel13. I'm simply trying to make sense of what he wrote on that specific excerpt.

Comment: Could you please point out at least some of those in the "stock full of logical holes," @EthanLeonard? Cheers; much appreciated.

Comment: @AndréLevy not you. I was referring to Strauss. Chag Sameach.

Comment: Aha! Let me not overstate the case, @Harel13; I'm not claiming Strauss said the Rambam covertly condemned circumcision; I haven't found references to that effect. Rather, I myself am asking whether the only way of making logical sense of these specific paragraphs in *Guide for the Perplexed* is to apply a Straussian interpretation (since Strauss himself seems to have learnt this directly from the Rambam).

Answer (score 0):

Rambam himself tells us in the introduction that he is weaving secrets into his work that only the clever will aduce. He also says that only one in a thousand will get what he is saying *in general*, let alone how few will get the *secrets*. Therefore it is highly inappropriate and dangerous for one to freely try to understand "hidden meaning" in Rambam, especially to prove one's own biased hypothesis.

To answer your four points, all you have to do is read the context:

- 2 is in a section that is acknowledging the pain involved - in this case the psychological pain to the parents - and what
  we do to successfully avoid that to be humane (a subject that is very important in
  Torah thought and is even discussed in the Tanach).
- 1 and 3 are discussing some of the meaning behind the mitzva (something Rambam does a lot in his writings, especially the guide - the mitzvot are replete with meaning and it is our duty to study that). I.e. in
  3 there is meaning in the togetherness generated, and in 1, he shows
  how that togetherness is secure because it's highly unlikely someone
  will go through such a strong operation to "infiltrate" the holy
  Torah community.
- 4 is demonstrating an important Torah principle: we avoid excessive
  lust, and circumcision helps both men and women with this, the latter of which is being proven by this single point you've brought. Note: we hold
  *excessive* lust to be very dangerous to marriage and holiness. It ruins intimacy and relationships, rather than makes them more refined and close.

Of course he was a big halachist and wrote the first comprehensive collection of all halachot in Torah and is considered a great authority on halacha. The mitzva of circumcision is one of Judaism's most important mitzvot (they are all equally important but there is a large disproportionate emphasis placed on this mitzva throughout all Torah writings and for this reason the Torah community will certainly never abandon it even under great pressure or threat). It is unthinkable that he would be against it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't find it convincing. I intentionally left out the reference to dulling sexual pleasure, as I understand the point above avoiding excessive lust, but that which Rambam finds to be "the strongest of the reasons for circumcision" simply says "it is hard for a woman with whom an uncircumcised man has had sexual intercourse to separate from him," not about excessive lust. He's saying being uncircumcised is marriage superglue.

Comment: Secondly, you say "it's highly unlikely someone will go through such a strong operation to "infiltrate" the holy Torah community," but mostly all the gentiles around Maimonides were Muslims, who've all had gone through this "strong operation." It's nonsensical; circumcision neither identified, nor united Jews, in the places the Rambam lived. I mean, I had already written all this in my question; it seems you didn't even read it, so... it's a neg from me.

Comment: Thanks @AndréLevy for the pushback, let's find the truth together. The Rambam is basing the point in the midrash rabbah which says that when Dina was raped it created a neurosis in her, in that she felt what might nowadays be described as a nymphomania, and spurred on the shameful guilty feelings of having been defiled. It is terrible. We joke, wouldn't it be nice if all our wives were nymphomaniacs but anyone genuinely suffering from this wouldn't wish it on anyone. It impairs life and relationships and is a curse not a blessing. The Rambam is saying it's the strongest reason for...

Comment: ... circumcision, not for NOT getting circumcised, so I don't follow your logic. Feel free to walk it through with me. I did read your whole post btw, but the pain was the answer, even if you didn't ask about it as a question. Muslims don't get the same circumcision as Jews, so the point still stands, and I'd argue there's no reason to think the Rambam was writing just about his time and place anywa.

Comment: Even if not writing just about his time and place, the mere fact that mostly all men around him were circumcised, would render that particular "reason" for circumcision moot; it may had been a mark of Jewish identity before Mohammed, but not anymore ever since. And Jewish circumcision too changed through the ages—right?—going from a small excision to full removal of the prepuce, so that circumcision is no less varied amongst Jews than it is between Jews and Muslims.

Comment: @AndréLevy but that's what he writes explicitly though? That it's a mark of a Jew for the sake of togetherness and to prevent infiltration. This is a meaning behind the mitzva, but not the meaning _of_ the mitzva, so it doesn't have to apply to all circumstances.

Comment: Indeed it is, but it is in such evident contradiction to his circumstances that one is left to wonder what he actually meant, if not explicitly, as that is rendered meaningless by contradiction, at least implicitly. And that in fact *is* Rambam's method, according to Strauss, especially in the *Guide*. He says in his writings that *Contradictions are the axis of the Guide.*

Comment: More explicitly, Green writes that Green writes that *Strauss came firmly to believe that Maimonides intentionally used contradictions as a mode of expression consistent with the truth, in order to preserve the rights of the free mind as 
well as to hint at truths he held which stood against conventional opinion or pious belief, in a period in which speaking the truth was both dangerous and unwise.* it seems to me this passage on circumcision is a perfect example of that.

Comment: Further to the contradiction to his circumstances, Rambam also states that *circumcision is likewise the [symbol of the] covenant which Abraham made in connection with the belief in God's Unity. So also everyone that is circumcised enters the covenant of Abraham to believe in the unity of God.* So he's not really saying circumcision is a mark of *Jewish* identity, but of monotheistic identity, which included pretty much everyone around him. Even the language of "belief in God's Unity" seems to be a direct reference to that hallmark call of Muslims: *Allahu Akbar*.

Comment: @AndréLevy if we pursue this line of thinking, it sounds like he's not arguing against circumcision, but arguing for more circumcision.

Comment: You mean that Christians ought to likewise circumcise, @RabbiKaii? How does that corroborate your point that he's advocating circumcision *for the sake of togetherness and to prevent infiltration*? Surely you're not suggesting the Rambam had some ecumenical goal in mind, are you?

Comment: @AndréLevy It's your argument, I am just taking it to its logical end, not commenting on the veracity of the argument itself. As for the argument itself the "Covenant of Abraham" is exclusively a Jewish covenant.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131814/31534

Answer (score 0):

Logical issues with your reading:

"convey their proper meaning" does not equal "adapt to the moral views of their time".

(Point 1 is quoted out of context, and it's really part of point 3. It clearly says that because it's so difficult, it creates a barrier to pretending to be Jewish, as well as creates a feeling of unity. But even if you quote it out of context as you did, ) describing a surgical procedure as difficult is not even a covert condemnation. It's just a description of medical fact.

Point 2 is also taken out of context, plus you clearly didn't read the link you quoted that carefully, or you would have seen that it **is in fact supported by Scripture**. He did not say that the father doesn't care about his son very much when he is 8 days old. What he said (very clearly, if you read the context) was that the father loves his son more every day, so the best time to have to inflict a necessarily painful procedure would be just after birth, but since the Torah informs us that until a week of life, a birthed creature doesn't really have vitality, it would not be safe to do so. He quotes Lev. xxii. 27 to make this point.

You also skipped the part where he said that the child will not be in much pain because of a baby's soft skin.

You also skipped the part where he said that because the baby has not been conditioned to fear pain, he won't suffer the dread of oncoming pain.

The fact that he lived in Muslim territories doesn't mean that should change the reason for the commandment given in the Torah, long before Muslims existed!

Point 4 is also taken out of context. He says in that paragraph that circumcision counters excessive lust. Then he says that that (countering excessive lust) is the intention of the Midrash when it says that it is hard for the woman to separate ... So the part you quoted is interpreted by Maimonides to mean that circumcision is intended to limit excessive lust, and that is the best reason for the commandment. Then he says that it is relevant that this commandment was first displayed with Abraham, who feared this type of sin greatly , even with regards to his own wife.

Besides, why would non-excessive lust prevent Jews from getting married or staying married? Jews get married before intimacy, so a Jewish woman should never experience the challenge of excessive lust before meeting and marrying her husband.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating your answer, @EthanLeonard. You say I've taken the quotes out of context, but the context is given by the passage which is linked. I didn't find it necessary, and even overly verbose, to reproduce it in full. Further, breaking down the passage in separate points is not taking them out of context; it's simply singling them out to be subsequently addressed, as I did.

Comment: But when you miss the main points of each paragraph, it is taking it out of context.

Comment: I understand the point of curbing excessive lust, as I addressed in my question, and seems to be the mainstream takeaway from this passage, but the question is: if it is indeed the case that *it is hard for a woman with whom an uncircumcised man has had sexual intercourse to separate from him*, why would the Rambam not want that to be the case for Jewish couples? How is that a *good* reason for circumcision?

Comment: *He did not say that the father doesn't care about his son very much when he is 8 days old.* No? Doesn't he explicitly write that *when a child is very young, the parents do not think much of him*? Doesn't he also explicitly say that *the parents' love for a new-born child is not so great*, and that *shortly after birth the image is very weak in the mind of the parent, especially of the father*?

Comment: When it says she finds it difficult to separate from him, that doesn't mean divorce.

Comment: If you only quote those words, which remember are translated and may lose some connotation, then I see how you could get lost. But if you read the whole paragraph, you see what is intended. Besides, "not so great" may not be a euphemism (i.e. it does not mean it is a small love), but just that it is not nearly as much as it would be. Remember that he also adds that by the age of 2 or 3, it would be a concern that the father could not bring himself to do it.

Comment: Yes as @EthanLeonard says, the difficulty in separation is a euphemism for her wanting to return to repeat the lustful experience. It's in the commentaries, I will try and find after Yom Tov bli neder. Chag samayach and shabbat shalom all