# How many descendants did Abraham have?

Tags: abraham

Sorry if the question doesn't belong here.
I'm not asking about the interpretation of the Bible verse promising countless descendants.

I would like to know if any one run the math to estimate the actual number of descendants as of today?

Comment: Might be better suited in maths stack exchange. The [Identical Ancestors Point or All Common Ancestors point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_ancestors_point) is the generation in our ancestry where a) if anyone has any descendants alive today, then everyone is their descendant or b) if someone doesn't have any descentants alive today, then they have no descendants. I think Avraham is easily in the right place and right time that the whole world (except the most isolated places) are his descentants. Most of the world? Total ancestors would be much harder to calculate

Comment: Jacob's ([who the promise applies to as well](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131808/does-the-covenant-with-abraham-affect-any-of-his-children-besides-the-children-o/131814#131814)) descendants are another story, due to them rarely marrying out. With the dispersion of the tribes and other factors though, could also be the case.

Comment: I know the wording is the same as the linked question, but that thread seems more a debate on how literal the promise of God was